# How to get only one object to toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been working with the toggle function on jquery, but I've been having some issues. I can successfully toggle one of my objects, but when I click on it, the hidden content for ALL of them reveals instead of the content for just that specific object.

Here's the relevant code:

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function () {
      $("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<button>Click me.</button><br />
<p style="display: none;">Word</p><br />
<button>Click me.</button>
<p style="display: none;">Word</p><br />
<button>Click me.</button>
<p style="display: none;">Word</p><br />
<button>Click me.</button>
<p style="display: none;">Word</p>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  display: block; 
  width: 90%; 
  height: 25px; 
  line-height: 10px; 
  background-color: #f4eb79; 
  color: #392e25; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  padding: 7px; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #2e7899;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #2e7899; 
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #2e7899; 
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s; 
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s; 
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button:hover
{
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #ff8eb3; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  border: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #1f5066; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #1f5066; 
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #1f5066;
}
```

Comment: You have to use `id` or `class` or some other property to identify which element you want to be affected by your toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method in jquery. I might also suggest wrapping your two elements in a div so you eliminate any reference issues if there are more than one of the same type of selector.

For example:

```
<div>
    <button>Click me.</button>
    <p style="display: none;">Word</p><br />
</div>
<div>
    <button>Click me.</button>
    <p style="display: none;">Word</p><br />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function () {
          $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide only one P at a time : 
1) you can use IDs  and use selectors acordingly
or you can wrap the button and p inside a div or span like :

```
<div>
<button>Click me</button>
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

your js then will be :

> $("button").click(function () {
>
> $(this).parents("div").children("p").slideToggle("slow");
>
> });

haven't tested but you get the idea

Comment: Rather than using `parents` followed by `children`, you might want to look into `siblings`.